# how to find and export each cell datatype into a csv using python

Tags: python, pandas, dask

What is the best way to loop through each line in CSV file and find and export the datatype of each cell into csv file?

Here is the python script I am using with pandas library,

```
import pandas as pd
out = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Sridhar\\Downloads\\Leads.csv")
dict(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here "data" should be the column of which cells data_type you want to know.

```
data_type = [type(d_type) for d_type in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # df is dataframe in which you wanted to add type column
df["data_type"] = data_type
df.to_csv("output.csv")
print(df)
```